# How can I add ActiveX object to ROT using Java and SWT?

Tags: java, com, activex

I am trying to link running ActiveX object as OleControlSite object to COM object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

ActiveX/COM uses low-level C++ pointers and relies heavily on Microsoft runtime support.  The Java JVM completely virtualizes away these kinds of low-level, OS- and system-specific details.

There are Java::COM/ActiveX bridges available.

You could probably also write your own JNI interface to one or another specific COM/ActiveX call.